# RDLC expression visibility of textbox (based on date)

Tags: date, compare, expression, reporting, rdlc

how can i write the expression for the visibility for the text box based on active date = today day?

=iif( Parameters!Activedate.Value == datetime.now ,True,False)

Answer (score 0):

In RDLC you don't set visibility to false, you set hidden to true. So, the opposite of what you have there?